# How to replace a string inside a list with a sub-list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

```
li = ['a', '#b', 'c']
repl = ['1', '2', '3']
```

I want to change `'#b'` with the `repl` sublist, meaning, this is my desired output:

```
['a', ['1', '2', '3'], 'c']
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
for i in li:
    if i.startswith('#'):
        i.replace(i, repl)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-151b36fac37c> in <module>()
      1 for i in li:
      2     if i.startswith('#'):
----> 3         i.replace(i, repl)

TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: `i.replace(..)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot replace a substring with a list. Instead, iterate over the list using a comprehension:

```
li = ['a', '#b', 'c']
repl = ['1', '2', '3']
new_li = [repl if i.startswith('#') else i for i in li]
```

Output:

```
['a', ['1', '2', '3'], 'c']
```

If you do not want to use list comprehension, you can either write out the entire generic loop, or use a functional approach:

Generic loop:

```
new_l = []
for i in li:
   if i.startswith('#'):
      new_l.append(repl)
   else:
      new_l.append(i)
```

Functional approach:

```
new_li = map(lambda x:repl if x.startswith('#') else x, li)
```

Comment: @ClementAttlee to be clear, you should *not* try to modify a list or its elements as you iterate through it. instead create a new list

Comment: What if for some practical reason I'd rather not use list comprehension?

Comment: @ClementAttlee then write out the full `for` loop

Answer (score 5):

inplace version

```
li = ['a', '#b', 'c']
repl = ['1', '2', '3']
for i, item in enumerate(li):
    if item.startswith('#'):
        li[i] = repl
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use list comprehension:

```
li = ['a', '#b', 'c']
repl = ['1', '2', '3']

for count, i in enumerate(li):
    if i.startswith('#'):
        li[count] = repl

print li

['a', ['1', '2', '3'], 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li = ['a', '#b', 'c']
repl = ['1', '2', '3']

x = li.index('#b')
li[x] = repl
print(li)
```

this should give the desired result

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a stack based approach:

```
li = ['a', '#b', 'c']
repl = ['1', '2', '3']

stack = []
for elem in li:
    stack.append(elem)
    if stack[-1].startswith("#"):
        stack.pop()
        stack.append(repl)

print(stack)
```

Which Outputs:

```
['a', ['1', '2', '3'], 'c']
```